# Solr: Fetching results with a minimum from each category

Tags: solr

I am using solr 4.4.0. The search is performed on products, each of which has a category field. I want to retrieve top n products. But, if some category has less than m products among the top n, then I want to retrieve more products only for those categories.

Eg. I have 4 categories a, b, c, d. n=20 and m=5. Now lets say the top 20(=n) have following category distribution (a:6, b:4, c:6, d:4). Categories b and d have less than m(=5) products. So I would like to fetch one more product(with the next highest score) for both these categories.

Is there a way I can do this using solr

Comment: fetch n no. of records each time and handle it by programatically

Answer (score 0):

Did you try to solve this with [FieldCollapsing](http://wiki.apache.org/solr/FieldCollapsing)?

You use group.field=category, and group.limit lets you set the size of each group. Then you need to be a bit careful on how the groups are sorted, I think it was by the first doc in the group...

But I guess you can achieve what you are looking for fairly easy.